# How to use linearity and monotone convergence to show $T_{s+t}\mathbb{1}_B=(T_tT_s)\mathbb{1}_B \Rightarrow T_{s+t}=T_tT_s$?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to show that the probability kernel $(p_t)$ satisfy the Chapman-Kolmogorov relation iff the corresponding transition operators $T_t$ have the semigroup property $$T_{s+t}=T_sT_t, \quad s,t\ge0.$$

For $B\in B(E)$ we now have
\begin{align*}
    (T_sT_t)\mathbb{1}_B(x)&=T_s(T_t\mathbb{1}_B)(x) =\int_E p_s(x,dy)(T_t\mathbb{1}_B)(y) \\
    &=\int_E p_s(x,dy)p_t(y,B)=p_{s+t}(x,B) =T_{s+t}\mathbb{1}_B(x).
\end{align*}

How do I use linearity and monotone convergence to extend to $T_{s+t}=T_sT_t$ exactly?

Comment: linearity shows the equality at simple functions. then take any non-negative function, and take simple functions increasing to it, then apply MCT to get the equality at that non-negative function. then you have it for any real-valued function by linearity